# Suggest good VoIP Mobile SDK (Android & iOS)?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, sdk, voip

The company I am working for plans to integrate VoIP functionality into our mobile applications.

Can anybody suggest some good VoIP Mobile SDKs he has worked with.

NB! Please, don’t suggest anything if you haven’t worked with it.

At the moment I am considering:

VaxVoIP - seems pretty good, trial ( huge plus ) and cheap ( 1,500$ per OS ). Unfortunately, no video capability.

VoipSwitch - again, seems good, no trial ( huge minus ), not so cheap ( 15,000$ per OS ). Video capability is included.

PS! The company is building commercial applications, so GPL license isn’t good for us.

Any help/comments/advice would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: that's not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Please Improve your Question.

Comment: Budius and Orion, thank you for your opinions. Could you, please, suggest what exactly should be improved? Since I have a problem of selecting a proper SDK which are quite expensive to try and throw away, so I'm searching for people with hands on experience with VoIP SDKs and StackOverflow looked like a good place for such search.

Comment: No it i's not. As you can see the reason your question will likely be closed very soon it's because asking for tools, libraries or services is not a valid question on StackOverflow. `SO` is about very direct programming questions. That you can show code, and people can suggest corrections to it. Probably try some forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VoipSwitch is a good option along with that you can checkout for asterisk, lots of vendor provider are available.

Comment: Thank you, Gourav. Have you actually bought it and used it yourself in your app, did it work ok for you? Because I have seen on forums some negative discussions about VoipSwitch and people regretted wasted money.

Comment: yes, we used in android, iphone, windows mobile 6.5 as well as blackbery. Blackebery got some issues but that was phone specific but on andriod, iphone and windows mobile it works great

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at siphon (http://code.google.com/p/siphon/).

From their homepage:

> Home of the World's first free
>   SIP/VoIP application for iPhone and
>   iPod Touch 1 and 2.
>
> Siphon SIP/VoIP project is the first
>   in his category that works on iPhone
>   and iPod Touch 2 with headset for all
>   SIP providers. It is a native
>   application approved running on 2.X
>   using internal micro/speaker and
>   headset.
>
> The Application supports the SIP
>   standard, preserving compatibility
>   with hundreds of SIP providers and
>   offers a GUI which preserves the apple
>   design of native iPhone applications.

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK it is iOS only, but we need Android as well and may be Windows later.